# How to perform a reverse command history search in redis-cli

Tags: redis

How do I do a reverse search on command history in redis-cli?
Typing the starting letters and pressing the up arrow doesn't work.
Neither does bash style 'ctrl+r'. Please help.

Is there a file where redis saves the command history.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How do I do a reverse search on command history in redis-cli?

`redis-cli` uses [linenoise](https://github.com/antirez/linenoise) which [does not support](https://github.com/antirez/linenoise/blob/cf1bdf5/linenoise.c#L52) (yet) reverse search within the history:

```
/* linenoise.c */
History search like Ctrl+r in readline?
```

> Is there a file where redis saves the command history?

That being said Redis saves the commands history under [`~/.rediscli_history`](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/93eed9a/src/redis-cli.c#L895) which can be obtained with up arrow key.

Also, it supports command auto-completion via the tab key.

Comment: Neither up-arrow nor tab completion work for my on Mac OS X.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [repl](http://defunkt.io/repl/) and [rlwrap](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap) to enable `reverse-i-search` on your redis-cli history via CTRL-r.  On Max OS X, I just installed both of these via brew:

```
brew install repl
brew install rlwrap
```

repl expects your history file to be named `~/.{command}_history`.  For `redis-cli` it expects `~/.redis-cli_history`, but on my Mac OS X installation, the history file was named `~/.rediscli_history`, so I had to symlink it like so:

```
ln -s ~/.rediscli_history ~/.redis-cli_history
```

You can now start the redis-cli by using `repl redis-cli` and reverse-i-search will be enabled.  You might want to add an alias to to make it more convenient to run this in the future by doing something like

```
alias rcli='repl redis-cli'
```